# docker tomcat в докер-контейнере не отображает страницы

Tags: java, docker

появилась нужда контейнеризировать моё JavaEE приложение. Создаю контейнер для mysql, он работает по логам. Создаю контейнер приложения, по логам все работает, к mysql контейнеру подключается. Но вот проблема, когда я в браузере обращаюсь по любому адресу, скажем, http://localhost:8080/login , то появляется проблема следующего рода, вылетает 404 ошибка `The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`

Когда перехожу на http://localhost:8080/ , то получаю страницу [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что подтверждает работу приложения в контейнере.

Без контейнера, когда запускаю приложение, все работает.

Вот пример страницы логина:

```
package api.servlets.authentication;

import api.service.AuthenticationService;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.authenticationService = (AuthenticationService) getServletContext().getAttribute("authenticationService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/login-page.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        final String email = request.getParameter("email");
        final String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if (authenticationService.isAuthenticated(email, password)){
            final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("email", email);
            response.sendRedirect("/tasks-menu");
        }else {
            response.setContentType("text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write("Неверный логин или пароль");
        }

    }
}

Вот структура проекта

[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]
```

Comment: я не в теме, просто мимопроходил, но если у вас стандартная страница показывается, а ваша какая то кастомная нет - то может вы томкат запустили, но приложение свое в нем не запустили?

Comment: покажите для начала Dockerfile

Comment: Каким образом добавляли приложение в томкат? Если .war файл загружали через админку томката (http://localhost:8080/manager), то видно приложение в админке? Путь к приложению должен быть таким: `http://localhost:8080/<название war файла до точки>/login`